# How to prevent a URL while indexing in to google?

Tags: indexing, seo, robots.txt

I have a development server where i have 100 websites(folders) placed but am pointing each and every folder with another domain, but still I can access the folder using server ip or domain right? How can i stop indexing the url which is opening by the server's ip or domain?

Eg:

Server is: myserver.com
Website(folder): mywebsite

I can access this like myserver.com/mywebsite

i have another domain called newwebsite.com and pointing to mywebsite folder which is present in myserver.com then I can access same folder using newwebsite.com, I need to stop indexing **myserver.com/mywebsite**.. Can any one help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every website you've added to the google repository you can add a file called `Robots.txt`. This file includes all your rules about:

1. Which pages and URLs will be indexed and followed.
2. Which URLs denies the crawler access as hidden points.
3. And all other rules you can read about in this [documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

For example you can block your favorite URLs in each domain(or subdomain) like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /~joe/junk.html
Disallow: /~joe/foo.html
```

Don't remember the robots.txt file must be placed in root directory of the each website to be detected by crawlers.
Regards